# ModSecurity, Create an IP Blacklist file

Tags: iis, mod-security, ip-blocking

We have a list of IPs that we want blocked.
I currently have them blocked at the firewall, I would like to create a file that ModSecurity will read, and block those IPs.
This is a pretty big list, as it has been created over a couple years.
Is there a way to do this with ModSecurity?

Comment: I came across this.  Would it suffice?
Obviously I need to create the blacklist.dat file.
***********************************************************

SecAction phase:1,nolog,pass,\
    setvar:TX.REMOTE_ADDR=/%{REMOTE_ADDR}/
*************************************************************************

    
SecRule "@pmFromFile blacklist.dat"\
    "phase:1,log,block,msg:'IP address on blacklist'"

Comment: How would this be beneficial in comparison to blocking them at the firewall?

Comment: I think I figured out the rule I need and got it work.
But we are moving to Azure, and the firewall option isn't there.
You get an NSG and/or a WAF, so in that case it is better to make ModSecurity do the work, maintaining a NSG would not be possible or desirable